# error 500 in asp page, Response_Buffer_Limit_Exceeded, find what operation is causing it

Tags: iis

I have an asp page that should load data with a query. After an update in the database, that should have populated the table that the query touch, the web page is suddently giving error 500. I inherited this windows 2003 machine with IIS.

The error message in the IIS logs is:

```
2019-06-03 12:19:24 W3SVC1 10.100.0.3 GET /Intranet/Q-Monitor_costi_produzione.asp username=username&x=1670|0|ASP_0251_:_80004005|Response_Buffer_Limit_Exceeded 80 - 10.100.0.78 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729) 500 0 0
```

Is there a way to see what portion of the page is giving this error?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Response_Buffer_Limit_Exceeded measn the execution of the ASP page caused the Response Buffer to exceed its configured limit.

To solve this issue ,I suggest you could follow below steps:

1.Open the IIS manager and click the ASP feature:

[image]

2.Change the Response Buffering Limit to 64000000(almost 64mb)

[image]